# Unable to hide a nested list wihch is inside a div

Tags: jquery, html-lists, hide

I am trying to hide a list that inside an other unordered list which is inside a div

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul class="menuoptions">
   <li>

    </li>

     <li>
    </li>

     <li class="Admin">

   </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I need to hide the third list in the undordered list.

This is what i tried but not working:

```
 $(#cssmenu .menuoptions ul.Admin).slice(3).hide();
```

Please help..

Comment: Your selector has syntax errors, it should be `$('li.Admin').hide()`

Comment: the problem is with your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `li.Admin` selector, the query returns only one element, so `.slice(3)` won't return any element to hide

```
$('#cssmenu .menuoptions li.Admin').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

you could just to:

```
$("li.Admin").hide();
```

or

```
$("#cssmenu").find("li.Admin").hide();
```

or

```
$("#cssmenu").find('li').eq(2).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css:

```
#cssmenu .menuoptions .Admin { 
    display:none; 
}
```

and with jQuery:

```
$('#cssmenu').find('li.Admin').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it via the class name as the other two answers propose, or if you really need the THIRD element:

```
$(#cssmenu .menuoptions li).eq(2).hide();
```

Btw, you are using `ul.Admin`, but in fact you have an `li.Admin`

Answer (score 0):

try this ...
this will help you to hide multiple class in ul list..

```
$("#cssmenu ul li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == "Admin")
            $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: there is many simple ways! did you look at other answers ? :)